# GraphQL field's resolver not getting called

Tags: express, graphql, apollo-server

I'm using apollo-server and testing using GraphiQL in my browser. I set up my resolvers based on Apollo's [GitHunt-API example](https://github.com/apollostack/GitHunt-API/blob/master/api/schema.js), but the resolver on the field "review.extraStuff" never gets called.

### Resolver

```
const rootResolvers = {
    review(root, args, context) {
        console.log('resolving review');
        return {'HasErrors': true}
    }
}

const extraStuff = (root, args, context) => {
    console.log('resolving extraStuff');
    return "yes";
}

rootResolvers.review.extraStuff = extraStuff;

export default {
    RootQuery: rootResolvers
};
```

### Schema

```
const Review = `
    type Review {
        HasErrors: Boolean
        extraStuff: String
    }
`

const RootQuery = `
    type RootQuery {
        review(id: String!): Review
    }
`;

const SchemaDefinition = `
    schema {
        query: RootQuery
    }
`;
```

### Query result from GraphiQL

[image: Query result from GraphiQL]

### Additional Info

I know that Apollo is aware of my extraStuff resolver because if I set "requireResolversForNonScalar" to true, I don't get a message telling me extraStuff is missing a resolve function. I've added logging to both the schema and the apolloExpress middleware and learned nothing.

Comment: extrastuff is a string and therefore a scalar

Comment: So, you're saying that "requireResolversForNonScalar" wouldn't catch it? That would make sense.

Comment: @w00t Care to elaborate at all? I'm looking through the graphql-tools source code because my problem seems to be in makeExecutableSchema. It looks like scalar fields are treated differently, but I'm still not clear what my exact problem is.

Comment: try making the field an object and see if you can make it work that way? Unfortunately I haven't actually tried graphql-tools yet :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My problem was that I didn't understand that the resolvers you pass into *makeExecutableSchema* (from graphql-tools) needs to map all your types to their own resolvers. In other words, every type should have a top-level entry in the resolvers object you pass to *makeExecutableSchema*.

Here's how I fixed my problem:

### Resolvers

```
const rootResolvers = {
    review(root, args, context) {
        console.log('resolving review');
        return {'HasErrors': true}
    }
}

const reviewResolvers = {
    extraStuff(root, args, context) {
        console.log('resolving extraStuff');
        return "yes";
    }
}

export default {
    RootQuery: rootResolvers
    Review: reviewResolvers
};
```

No changes were necessary in my schema, or anywhere else for that matter.